# How do I unclog outside water drainage pipe?

Tags: plumbing

Can anyone help me identify the type of grate overlaying this pipe, inform me of the proper tools to open it, and the follow-up to clear it properly and thoroughly? Clearly this pipe must be unclogged. Heavy Rainwater routinely threatens to flood into the basement and soak the carpet.

How do I begin?

Seeing as a picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a grate exactly like that one in my basement floor drain. You should be able to flip it up with a flat screwdriver or similar tool and pull it out of the way so you can run a snake down the drain.

I would start by using a shopvac to clear all the water above the drain. Then pull off the grate and start snaking. Impossible to guess how far you will need to go.

The big question is "what" is clogging in the drain. Since this is outside, it could be connected to your main drain and have "normal" drain clogs - e.g., lint, grease, etc. that a snake can relatively easily get through. But it is also possible that it is roots (which a snake can handle, but is sometimes quite a bit of rock) or even accumulated dirt/sand/gravel which may be really tough to break through. Only way to know is to try.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the bottom picture, the left side may or may not be hinged so proceed as if it is. Try prying the grate from the right side carefully since the grate is probably cast iron. I have a similar grate cover, however mine is PVC plastic and the drain it is attached to is the french drain which runs around my house. If you get it to lift up, all you need to do is clean up the mating surfaces of the grate and the receptacle.